# Calling a windows common dialog from a command line application

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, command-line

Is it possible to call a windows common dialog and retrieve its output from within a command line application?  I'd like to build most of my application to run from the console, since in my particular case it would SERIOUSLY reduce complexity; however, I would like to be able to pop up a folder selector dialog to let the user pick out a directory.  I'd just like to avoid the overhead of creating a full-blown GUI app.

I'd be doing this in C++, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, you can use a GUI toolkit and still do console I/O. Why not?

Comment: I know, but I think doing it this way will look cleaner considering the ONLY thing I need the GUI for is to accept the folder path from the user.  Everything else will be on the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    BROWSEINFO bi = {0};
    bi.lpszTitle = "Pick a Directory";
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder (&bi);
    if (pidl != 0) {
        TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
        if (SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, path)) {
            std::cout << path << "\n";
        }

        IMalloc* imalloc = 0;
        if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetMalloc(&imalloc))) {
            imalloc->Free(pidl);
            imalloc->Release();
        }
    }
}
```

(taken from http://vcfaq.mvps.org/sdk/20.htm)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted to do.  Thanks!

Comment: Done!  Sorry, I didn't know I could select it as the answer AND upvote it.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

The common dialogs provided by the Windows SDK can be called from a console application. You just need to check their individual requirements. Some require a COM single threaded apartment (STA).

When showing the dialogs you can set the owner window to nullptr. Alternatively if you would like the dialog to be modal with respect to the console window you can use the GetConsoleWindow function to get the window handle used by the console. You can then pass this window handle to the dialog as its owner.

Here’s an example of using using GetConsoleWindow with the standard task dialog:

```
int main()
{
    TaskDialog(GetConsoleWindow(),
               nullptr, // module
               L"Title",
               L"Instruction",
               L"Content",
               TDCBF_OK_BUTTON,
               TD_INFORMATION_ICON,
               nullptr); // button
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the GetConsoleWindow() function...that's useful.  I did have to define the preprocessor variable _WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 before it would work, though.

Comment: Which would require a COM STA? They're so old, they even predate COM and threading.

Comment: Many of the newer dialogs provided by the shell require COM, most notably those introduced with Windows Vista to replace the older dialogs. For an example look at IFileDialog.

Answer (score 1):

Just use generic `DialogBoxParam` or `DialogBoxIndirectParam`  to create your dialog.

You will have to write appropriate callbacks and handle the user input. Actually it's not a big difference whether you create your windows from console application or from `winapi`-like.

*The only difference in visual terms is that the second one hides it's console by the default.*

If you wish, you could always stick to something like `Qt` or `wxWidgets`, if it's not an overkill.

Comment: Thanks for this tip...I can see where this would be especially useful if I wanted to create my own dialog resources and call them from the command line.